# Azure API Management: Using OAuth to secure a connection between the gateway and a backend?

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-api-management

We have an existing backend that is protected by a standard OAuth credentials flow. We are moving all traffic to pass through an Azure API gateway, and have found the following policy to use OAuth (source: [Use OAuth2 for authorization between the gateway and a backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure//////api-management/policies/use-oauth2-for-authorization?toc=api-management/toc.json)).

```
<!-- The policy defined in this file provides an example of using OAuth2 for authorization between the gateway and a backend. -->
<!-- It shows how to obtain an access token from AAD and forward it to the backend. -->

<!-- Send request to AAD to obtain a bearer token -->
<!-- Parameters: authorizationServer - format https://login.windows.net/TENANT-GUID/oauth2/token -->
<!-- Parameters: scope - a URI encoded scope value -->
<!-- Parameters: clientId - an id obtained during app registration -->
<!-- Parameters: clientSecret - a URL encoded secret, obtained during app registration -->

<!-- Copy the following snippet into the inbound section. -->

<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
      <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="20" response-variable-name="bearerToken" mode="new">
        <set-url>{{authorizationServer}}</set-url>
        <set-method>POST</set-method>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
          <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body>
          @{
          return "client_id={{clientId}}&resource={{scope}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}&grant_type=client_credentials";
          }
        </set-body>
      </send-request>

      <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>
          @("Bearer " + (String)((IResponse)context.Variables["bearerToken"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])
      </value>
      </set-header>

      <!--  Don't expose APIM subscription key to the backend. -->
      <set-header exists-action="delete" name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"/>
  </inbound>
  <backend>
    <base />
  </backend>
  <outbound>
    <base />
  </outbound>
  <on-error>
    <base />
  </on-error>
</policies>
```

However, the policy does not seem to reuse a token, and it thereby fetches a new one per call. This is not optimal mainly due to performance, but also because our agreement with Auth0 has a limit on the number of these calls.

Is there any way to reuse the token (if it is still valid) when doing calls between the gateway and the backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using cache-store-value and cache-get-value to store token in cache. If you inspect token beforehand you could put int into cache with it's expiration time as ttl. Just make sure to have a fallback logic in case cached token doesn't work.

There is no easy way to reuse policies, so retry part may look cumbersome. But it's only necessary if you want to retry call on 401 response to cached token.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup-value key="bearerToken" variable-name="bearerToken" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(!context.Variables.ContainsKey("bearerToken"))">
                <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="20" response-variable-name="bearerToken" mode="new">
                    <set-url>{{authorizationServer}}</set-url>
                    <set-method>POST</set-method>
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>@("client_id={{clientId}}&resource={{scope}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}&grant_type=client_credentials")</set-body>
                </send-request>
                <set-variable name="bearerToken" value="@((string)((IResponse)context.Variables["bearerToken"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])" />
                <cache-store-value key="bearerToken" value="@((string)context.Variables["bearerToken"])" duration="60" />
                <set-variable name="cachedToken" value="@(false)" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-variable name="cachedToken" value="@(true)" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>

        <!--  Don't expose APIM subscription key to the backend. -->
        <set-header exists-action="delete" name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"/>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <retry condition="@((bool)context.Variables["cachedToken"] && context.Response.StatusCode == 401)" count="1" interval="0" first-fast-retry="true">
            <choose>
                <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 401)">
                    <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="20" response-variable-name="bearerToken" mode="new">
                        <set-url>{{authorizationServer}}</set-url>
                        <set-method>POST</set-method>
                        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                            <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
                        </set-header>
                        <set-body>@("client_id={{clientId}}&resource={{scope}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}&grant_type=client_credentials")</set-body>
                    </send-request>
                    <set-variable name="bearerToken" value="@((string)((IResponse)context.Variables["bearerToken"]).Body.As<JObject>()["access_token"])" />
                    <cache-store-value key="bearerToken" value="@((string)context.Variables["bearerToken"])" duration="60" />
                    <set-variable name="cachedToken" value="@(false)" />
                </when>
            </choose>

            <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
                <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["bearerToken"])</value>
            </set-header>

            <forward-request />
        </retry>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Vitaliy. Do you by any chance have a complete example with fallback logic? Coding in xml is not really my strong side.

Comment: Thanks alot Vitaliy. This was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and easiest way is as below which also leverages the 'expires_in' as to set cache duration:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <cache-lookup-value key="cachedToken" variable-name="access_token" />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(!context.Variables.ContainsKey("access_token"))">
            <send-request ignore-error="true" timeout="20" response-variable-name="response" mode="new">
                <set-url>{{authorizationServer}}</set-url>
                <set-method>POST</set-method>
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>@("client_id={{clientId}}&resource={{scope}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}&grant_type=client_credentials")</set-body>
            </send-request>
            <set-variable name="responseObject" value="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["response"]).Body.As<JObject>())" />
            <set-variable name="access_token" value="@((string)((JObject)context.Variables["responseObject"])["access_token"])" />
            <set-variable name="expires_in" value="@((int)((JObject)context.Variables["responseObject"])["expires_in"])" />
            <cache-store-value key="cachedToken" value="@((string)context.Variables["access_token"])" duration="@(((int)context.Variables["expires_in"]) - 10)" />
        </when>
    </choose>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["access_token"])</value>
    </set-header>
    <!--  Don't expose APIM subscription key to the backend. -->
    <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```